# Add Date to Recent Posts Widget?

Tags: recent-posts

I am having an impossible time finding the proper way to add a date below the recent posts widget links.  If anybody has a code, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a default feature which by default is set not to show the post date. Here is the part of the code responsible to show/hide the post date

```
<?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
    <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To enable the post date, just check the *Display post date?* checkbox

[image]

### EDIT

Here is an idea how to change the post date format (*or for that matter changing the post date to anything*) for only the recent post widget

Here we will run a filter function on the [`get_the_date` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) inside the [`widget_display_callback` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_display_callback/). We will use the parameters passed to the `widget_display_callback` filter to target only the recent post widget only when the `show_date` instance is set to true

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', function ( $instance, $widget_instance )
{
    if (    $widget_instance->id_base === 'recent-posts'
         && $instance['show_date']    === true
    ) {

        add_filter( 'get_the_date', function ( $the_date, $d, $post )
        {
            // Set new date format
            $d = 'Y-m-d';
            // Set new value format to $the_date
            $the_date = mysql2date( $d, $post->post_date );

            return $the_date;   
        }, 10, 3 );

    }
    return $instance;
}, 10, 2 );
```

You can use the idea above to target the post title and permalink of the post via the `the_title` and the [`post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/) filters respectively in the recent posts widget. The above idea is also not just restricted to the recent post widget.

If you need anymore control over the output, I would suggest that you copy the recent posts widget to your custom plugin and then modifying it as necessary